# JPA join between a class that has two fields of the same type

Tags: jpa, join

I have the following class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
    public class Entity extends Model
    {
       @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinTable(name = "entity_owner", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
       private Set<UserAccount> owners;

       @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinTable(name = "entity_assignee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
       private Set<UserAccount> assignees;
    }
```

I have a user account that I want to be able to being back all the Entity objects that have the user in either the owners or the assignees.

I tried this, which almost works, but seems to being back some sort of cartesian result:

```
String query = "SELECT r FROM models.Entity r LEFT JOIN r.assignees a LEFT JOIN r.owners n ";
query += "WHERE a.id = 1 OR n.id = 1";
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the UserAccount is in both owners and assignees, seems like the query will duplicate a result, you can use DISTINCT to filter duplicated results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When there is instance of UserAccount already available for filtering results, 
[MEMBER OF](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_collection_member) expression can be used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(e) 
FROM SomeEntity e 
WHERE :someUser MEMBER OF e.assignees OR 
      :someUser MEMBER OF e.owners

UserAccount ua ...
em.createQuery(jpql).setParameter("someUser", ua)
```

If because of some reason query similar to original query is preferred, then adding DISTINCT is enough.